# VueRouter is changing the route even before calling Vue.beforeCreate function

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am new to vue.js and I am facing problem in initializing the router.

When user hits '/' I want to redirect to '/home' if the user has already signed in else redirect him to '/login'. On successful login, I am saving the access token in localStorage. Whenever the user revisits the page, I am fetching the token from localStorage and setting in my vuex store and redirecting him accordingly.

But the problem is even if user is already signed in, it always redirect to '/login' page. The call to router is getting executed before setting the token in store.

Below is my code. Please let me know how can I solve this.

```
//main.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import App from './App';
import { store } from './store';
import router from './router';

Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;


/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
  beforeCreate () {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('userToken');
    this.$store.dispatch('autoSignInToken', token);
  }
});

//router.js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Login from '@/components/User/Login';
import Hello from '@/components/Hello';
import AuthGuard from './auth-guard'

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      redirect: '/home',
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login,
      beforeEnter: AuthGuard
    },
    {
      path: '/home',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Hello,
      beforeEnter: AuthGuard,
    },
  ],
});

//auth-guard.js
import {store} from '../store'

export default (to, from, next) => {
  if (store.getters.user) {
    if(to.fullPath === '/login') {
      next('/home');
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } else {
    if(to.fullPath !== '/login') {
      next('/login');
    } else {
      next();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's not reason that you have to add the token in `beforeCreate` at all, is there? You don'T access the Vue instance at all, you only work with localStorage and the store.

So just do it before you even create the router.

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('userToken');
store.dispatch('autoSignInToken', token);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
  // ...
```

Comment: Thanks.. Didn't thought way..  It works perfectly fine.